# Full bootstrap markdown height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to change the markdown height to fill div height but I can't make it.

I have the following files -

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="admin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="md-editor active half-width">
        <textarea id="target-editor" class="target-editor-twitter md-input"> </textarea>
      </div>

      <div id="result" class="half-width">
      </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/markdown.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/to-markdown.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('#target-editor').markdown({
    savable:true,
    onShow: function(e){
      e.hideButtons("cmdPreview");
    },
    onSave: function(e) {
      alert("Saving '"+e.getContent()+"'...")
    },
    onChange: function(e){
      var content = e.parseContent()
      $('#result').html(content);
    }
  });
};
```

**admin.css**

```
body, html{
  height:100%;
}

.half-width{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
```

and the output is -

[image]

How to change markdown height to fill div height?

Comment: If I get you right, you want it to fill the whole page-height?

Comment: The plugin has a `height` option.. did you try that? see under Usage section http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/

Comment: @Evochrome yes!

Comment: @RajshekarReddy yes it can get % only px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at snippet

```js
window.onload = function(){
  $('#target-editor').markdown({
    savable:true,
    onShow: function(e){
        //e.hideButtons("cmdPreview");
  e.$textarea.css('resize','vertical');
  e.$textarea.css('height', ($(".md-editor").height()-90)+'px');
    },
    onSave: function(e) {
      alert("Saving '"+e.getContent()+"'...")
    },
    onChange: function(e){
      var content = e.parseContent()
      $('#result').html(content);
    }
  });
}; 
$(window).resize(function(){
 $("#target-editor").height(($(".md-editor").height()-90)+'px');
});
```

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
}

.half-width{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
  position:relative;
}
.md-editor>.md-header {
 margin-left: 5px;
}
.md-editor {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.2.1/js/bootstrap-markdown.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-markdown/2.2.1/css/bootstrap-markdown.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="half-width">
        <textarea id="target-editor" class="target-editor-twitter md-input" data-provide="markdown-editable" rows="20"> </textarea>
      </div>

      <div id="result" class="half-width">
      </div>
```

Comment: I've changed an answer. look at snippet